# Storing executable line options in array

Tags: bash, shell

I have an array.

```
ARR=("option1" "option with space" "option3")
```

if I have an executable which is to be run in this way

```
executable "option1" "option with space" "option3"
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just run it like this:

```
arr=("option1" "option with space" "option3")

executable "${arr[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the array's contents to the executable as,

```
<executable> "${ARR[@]}"
```

Double-quoting the array's contents is important here, and losing it would leave the option having spaces in it.

An illustration with an example:-

```
dudeOnMac:~$ touch file
dudeOnMac:~$ touch "file with spaces"
dudeOnMac:~$ ls
file            file with spaces
dudeOnMac:~$ touch "file_with@symbols"
dudeOnMac:~$ ls
file            file with spaces    file_with@symbols
dudeOnMac:~$ fileList=("file" "file with spaces" "file_with@symbols")
dudeOnMac:~$ ls "${fileList[@]}"
file            file with spaces    file_with@symbols
dudeOnMac:~$ ls -1tr "${fileList[@]}"
file
file with spaces
file_with@symbols
```